# CSS3 transition for element dimensions not working from percentage or auto to pixel size

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am building a single page website which shows a vector graphic of 80% screen width on the 'start screen'. Once the user scrolls down, the graphic transitions to a navigation bar at the top of the page and shall receive a hight of 50px. The transition from large to small dimensions should be animated with CSS3 transitions.

However, CSS transistions seem to not work when scaling an element from a percent or auto value to a fixed pixel value and vice versa. I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx11o942/) to demonstrate the effect. While the height of the div transitions well, the width is not animated at all.

Using pixel widths for the initial size of the image is not an option for responsive design reasons. The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            background-color: #010101;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .navbar--logo-item{
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 10px;
            width: 80%
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .navbar--logo-item.small{
            height: 50px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#toggle').click(function(){
                $('.navbar--logo-item').toggleClass('small');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar--logo-item"></div>
    <button id="toggle">
        Toggle Logo
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers, that can be solved using calc.

You can transition a calc value as long as it is homogeneous. 
Your case can be expressed in an homogeneous way as follows

```
.navbar--logo-item{
    width: calc(80% + 0px);
}
.navbar--logo-item.small{
    width: calc(0% + 200px);
}
```

Notice that the 2 calc are similar (they sum a percentage and a pixel value), but at the same time the result is the same that you already have

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx11o942/1/)

Another usual way to get this is to set a max-width on the higher posible original value, something like

```
.navbar--logo-item{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1000px; /* you don't need to set an accurate value */
}
.navbar--logo-item.small{
    max-width: 200px;   /* no need to set width */
}
```

Comment: While this seems to be a good way, I've just realized, that my issue is a little bit more complicated. I am using auto as a dimension value. width: calc(auto +0px) seems not to work to my regret. I am going to update my question...

Comment: Added another way to handle this. Not perfect, but can work if the initial width is in a somewhat limited range

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of your logo to that of its' immediate parent then everything is in pixels and the transition will take place as you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var logo = $('.navbar--logo-item');
    
    function setWidthtoParent(target) {
        var parentWidth = target.parent().width();
        target.css('width', parentWidth);
    }
    
    setWidthtoParent(logo);
    
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        logo.toggleClass('small');
    });
});
```

```css
html, body{
  background-color: #010101;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar--logo-item{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar--logo-item.small{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="navbar--logo-item"></div>
 <button id="toggle">
  Toggle Logo
 </button>
</body>
```

This is not ideal as it necessitates adding an `!important` declaration to over-ride the applied inline style. You also run the risk of the browser window being resized before the transition takes place. A better solution would be to use a consistent unit (perhaps transitioning the width of a parent div whilst your SVG remains at 100%, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/8oezd4kh/)).